# Any recommendations for writing dynamically created Python classes in C

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I'm working on a project where I need to create Python classes in C. As far as I have read, I've only seen examples where they write the classes statically, for example

```
static PyTypeObject myclassType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "mymodule.myclass",             /* tp_name */
    sizeof(myclass),                /* tp_basicsize */
    // etc.
}
```

But in the project, I need to create classes dynamically. E.g.

```
someclass = calloc(sizeof(PyTypeObject));
someclass.tp_methods = malloc(...);
```

The members and methods all depend on runtime.

Is there good examples out there about how to do it? I have concerns on issues such as, when do I have to deallocate tp_members or tp_name, etc.

Comment: I think you'll need to create the C equivalent of a Python metaclass (the class of the dynamically created classes). The default predefined on would be built-in `class 'type'` unless you have defined/derived your own metaclasses for the dynamically created classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more context. What problem are you trying to solve, in particular?

For example, if you are creating classes to attach behavior, there is already [support in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) for loading and calling C code. You could use that, and create the class interface in python and load the C libraries as part of the module init code.

Alternatively, if you are generating code based on a specification, it might be easier to parse the specification in python and generate the appropriate code directly. (Python is a [pretty good parsing language](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm). ;-)

If you are trying to embed C in your Python, you might consider [embedding a Python interpreter into your C](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html). That would give you the ability to set up your C code, then run python scripts, and call back to C.